# Copy Address of Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there some way in Excel to copy the address of a cell?

I need to copy the address of a cell from another worksheet into a formula on the current worksheet. To do this, I have to manually enter in the address of that cell, copy the address, then paste it into the different parts of the formula. It would be easier if I could just select the cell and click to copy its address.

Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a paste special and paste the link and it will remember the cell reference.

So, select and copy the cell you want to, then right click the cell you want to reference from. Within paste special, you have the option to select link (on the bottom row of icons in Excel 2010)

Obviously, when you paste it, it will then reference the value of the cell so it may appear as if you've only copied and pasted the value, but if you navigate to the new cell, you will see an absolute cell reference.

If you experience an issue when pasting a range, that it tells you there are no links, then you have to paste it twice. The first paste will inform you there is no link to paste. On the second attempt of pasting, it works.

Answer (score 2):

- Click (select) the cell you want to copy the address of.

  The address of the cell selected is shown in the excel Name Box, which is immediately above the upper-left-hand corner of the worksheet frame.
- Click the name box and  Ctrl-C (to copy the address) or right-click it & Copy.